# PHP socket_read returns empty string

Tags: php, sockets

I wrote a PHP class for a websocket client that allows you to connect to websocket servers from PHP. It works very well, except that it can only read data in an infinite loop. In a websocket connection, the server or the client can send data whenever they want, as many times as they want. Unfortunately, `socket_select`, `socket_read`, and `socket_recv` won't block if *any* data has been sent by the other socket - `socket_select` will return immediately, and `socket_read` and `socket_recv` will return an empty string. I tried making the process sleep until it received `SIGPOLL`, but that caused it to sleep indefinitely. Is there any way to know more data is available on the socket after data has already been received?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but it sounds like you should consider an evented approach (well, not really evented unless you implemented it that way), such as http://php.net/socket_select

Comment: @Corbin: <code>socket_select</code> returns immediately if any data is on the socket, regardless of whether or not you've read it already. The docs clarify it as "checking if a read will not block", and since both <code>socket_read</code> and <code>socket_recv</code> will not block (they return empty strings), it returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is not a good language to go forth with this as it is not an asynchronous language. I would suggest Node.js or something similar.

I may not know much about PHP and websockets, but couldn't you just loop it until you hit `SIGPOLL`?

Comment: Waiting for `SIGPOLL` didn't work for me, although I'm not sure I set it up correctly - I used `pcntl_sigwaitinfo(array(SIGPOLL));`, but do I have to block `SIGPOLL` first?